# PPTP Through IPTables

Tags: iptables, firewall, pptp

I have recently implemented a Raspberry Pi firewall/gateway on my network running iptables.

Ever since the implementation, I am unable to connect to a Windows-based PPTP server at my job.

I thought that I had an "allow everything that's going out" rule, but I guess not.  Entire iptables script listed bellow.

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth1 -j REJECT

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Here is my results from iptables -L -vn; iptables -t nat -L -vn:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   21  1572 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9   656 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1723 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:1723 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  eth1   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     47   --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    9   498 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth1   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   11  1212 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 64 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1723 to:192.168.1.51
    0     0 DNAT       47   --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.1.51

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    64 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: PPTP (really? Still? It's been insecure for very long now) uses GRE encapsulation. I don't know whether that will be matched with `ESTABLISHED,RELATED`, you may need to explicitly allow that (`-p 47` if I recall correctly). What's your outside interface? eth1? Please show `iptables -L -vn; iptables -t nat -L -vn` output, then at least the chains are shown sequentially.

Comment: Hey wurtel.  Thanks for the response.  I edited my question to include the results that you requested.  I had tried numerous things to try to allow GRE/47, but it wouldn't work.  I could have been doing it wrong, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've formatted it so it's readable :) (add 4 spaces to the begin for preformatted text.) I see no reason why it shouldn't work, although perhaps the direction of port 1723 should be reversed, ditto for protocol 47 (and you have `eth1` twice on one line). Unless I'm misreading eth0 and eth1; eth0 is internal network, right? Perhaps using `tcpdump` on the "internet" interface, limiting capture to the pptp server, might cast some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the formatting!.... I tried, I promise, lol.I'm assuming that you mean to reverse the "PREROUTING" rules?  I reversed them and when I did, it acts like nothing at all is getting out.  Without reversing them, I at least get to a "Verifying Password" notification, but nothing more.  You are correct though....eth0 is internal LAN and eth1 is Internet/WAN connection.

Comment: Did you fix the FORWARD rule with `-p 47 -i eth1 -o eth1`, which doesn't make much sense? (That's what I meant with *you have eth1 twice on one line*).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`modprobe ip_nat_pptp`

I also was not able to connect from my LAN even though all rules were very relaxed.

Comment: This.  I also came across the same problem in a different question.